# Can't stop my Node.JS app

Tags: node.js

I have [this app](https://github.com/thelucif3r/public_transportation_app) running on localhost:3000 and I don't know how to terminate the application. I no longer have the application running in my terminal, but whenever I go to localhost:3000, the app is still alive and well.

When I try to deploy another app on that port, it's ignored and returns the aforementioned app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of missing information here... how you terminate depends on your OS.  If you started it interactively in your terminal though, and it's no longer in your terminal... it's probably not still running.  And, when you say you have problems deploying another app on that port... deploying how?  It's impossible to help you without more detail.

Comment: I apologize for being vague. Here is what's happening in full: I started a node application from the terminal. It ended up running on port 3000. I stopped the application using ctrl+c. Next I start up a different application that decides to use port 3000 as well. BUT when I visit port 3000 I see the first application instead!

Comment: Still not sure how we can help you without knowing what OS you're using...

Comment: Sorry @Brad, I'm on a OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the application on linux, mac, windows?

If so you can run a command to stop a process running on port :xxxx

**linux & mac**:

This will print out processes running on the port

```
lsof -i:3000
```

then run

```
kill -9 process_id_here
```

**Windows:**

```
netstat -aon | findstr [port number]
```

#### Edit:

Forgot to add the instruction to kill a process on windows, here it is:

```
Taskkill /PID <process_id> /F
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can do this too on Linux/Mac:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

and then find the pid.

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

PS: Just in case if you are not sure of the port the process is running in.